# How to get macro name __LINE__ for a multi-line macro call?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have created a macro for error tracing.
Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERR(...)                                 \
    printf("error @ %d\n", __LINE__)

int main()
{
    return ERR(1,               /* line 7 */
               2,               /* line 8 */
               3);              /* line 10 */
}
```

When executed, it prints:

```
error @ 10
```

However, to match the printed line number with `grep` output (`grep -n ERR test.c`), I need line number of the `ERR` string (`line 7`).

Is such thing even possible? Any ideas?

Additional notes: 
the macro should look like a function call (so I can do `return ERR(...);`).
The compiler is GCC version 4.4.5. C99 + GNU extensions can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bases on @cwyang proposition, use macros with mismatched parenthesis in the definition and the coma operator.

```
#define ERR (LINEINFO, HANDLEARGS
#define HANDLEARGS(...) __LINE__)
#define LINEINFO printf("error @ %d: ", __LINE_)

return ERR(x,
           y,
           z);
```

will expand to

```
return (printf("error @ %d: ", 5), 7);
```

with gcc.

Comment: This seems to do what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Oh the joys of the C preprocessor.

Comment: Oh hello 5 year ago me.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```
#define VOID_MACRO(...) (void) 0
#define ERR printf("err @ %d\n", __LINE__); VOID_MACRO
```

Comment: It has a problem: The `VOID_MACRO` is never called when `ERR` is used as a `return` value (see additional notes in the question). However, it should be always called -- there is some functionality that makes use of the variadic arguments (it is not shown in my simplified example).

Comment: This partially solves the problem with return `#define ARG_MACRO(...) returns1_and_processes_args(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERR printf("error @ %d: ", __LINE__) * ARG_MACRO`. Not a perfect solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an option?

```
#define ERR(line,...)             \
    printf("error @ %d\n", line)

ERR(__LINE__
    blah,
    blah,
    blah);
```

Comment: (The easy/sane solution is to not use variable argument macros at all)

Comment: In non-simplified version variable argument macros are used for the error printing -- they cannot be avoided.

Comment: Having `__LINE__`s written all over the place (wherever the `ERR` macro is) is unwanted. The macro should take as little arguments as possible.

Comment: @Lundin, I fail to see how this is related to variable argument macros.

Comment: @AProgrammer If the macro had one or no parameters, then different cases of row formatting wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Lundin, if the macro had 3 parameters, the same problem would appear, so not using variable argument is simply not a solution, sane or not, easy or not.